# Highcharts - setData() not updating Column Graph Correctly - stumped

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highcharts Column graph that I am updating using setData() that is triggered by a User Selected Drop Down.  I am sure that the code was working correctly before, but now it does not trigger the setData() correctly.  Please see my JS Fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/mshirk/6QYzD/18/

Here is my javascript and HTML

```
    $(function () {
    var chartBench;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chartBench = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'containerYo',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                lineColor: '#999',
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickColor: '#666',
                tickLength: 3,
                categories: ['2011', '2012', '2013', '2014'],
                title: {
                    text: 'Years'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                lineColor: '#999',
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickColor: '#666',
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickLength: 3,
                gridLineColor: '#ddd',
                labels: {
                    format: '$ {value}'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Value A',
                data: [
                    [201],
                    [211],
                    [221],
                    [131]
                ]


            }, {
                name: 'Value B',
                data: [
                    [192],
                    [202],
                    [212],
                    [122]
                ]


            }, {
                name: 'Value C',
                data: [
                    [183],
                    [193],
                    [203],
                    [113]
                ]


            }, {
                name: 'Value D',
                data: [
                    [174],
                    [184],
                    [194],
                    [104]
                ]


            }]



        });
    });


    $("#list").on('change', function () {
        //alert('f')
        var selVal = $("#list").val();
        var selValB = $("#listb").val();
        var selValBB = $("#listc").val();

        if (selVal == "a" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "a") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [201],
                [211],
                [221],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [192],
                [202],
                [212],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [193],
                [203],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [174],
                [184],
                [194],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "a" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "b") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [201],
                [211],
                [221],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [192],
                [202],
                [212],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [193],
                [203],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [174],
                [184],
                [194],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "a") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [201],
                [211],
                [221],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [192],
                [202],
                [212],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [193],
                [203],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [174],
                [184],
                [194],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "b") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [141],
                [111],
                [121],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [132],
                [102],
                [112],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [123],
                [93],
                [103],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [114],
                [84],
                [94],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "a") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [201],
                [211],
                [221],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [192],
                [202],
                [212],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [193],
                [203],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [174],
                [184],
                [194],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "b") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [141],
                [111],
                [121],
                [131]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [132],
                [102],
                [112],
                [122]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [123],
                [93],
                [103],
                [113]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [114],
                [84],
                [94],
                [104]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "a" && selValB == "b" && selValBB == "a") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [151],
                [251],
                [221],
                [231]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [172],
                [242],
                [212],
                [222]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [233],
                [203],
                [213]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [154],
                [224],
                [194],
                [204]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "a" && selValB == "b" && selValBB == "b") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [151],
                [251],
                [221],
                [231]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [172],
                [242],
                [212],
                [222]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [233],
                [203],
                [213]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [154],
                [224],
                [194],
                [204]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "b" && selValBB == "a") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [151],
                [251],
                [221],
                [231]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [172],
                [242],
                [212],
                [222]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [183],
                [233],
                [203],
                [213]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [154],
                [224],
                [194],
                [204]
            ]);

        } else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "b" && selValBB == "b") {
            chartBench.series[0].setData(
            [
                [141],
                [151],
                [161],
                [171]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[1].setData(
            [
                [132],
                [142],
                [172],
                [162]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[2].setData(
            [
                [123],
                [133],
                [183],
                [153]
            ]);
            chartBench.series[3].setData(
            [
                [114],
                [124],
                [194],
                [144]
            ]);

        } else {

        }
    });

}); 


    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px;">
    <div>1: <select id="list">
    <option id="optiona" value="a" selected=yes >Option A</option> 
    <option id="optionb" value="b">Option B</option>
    </select></div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="containerYo" style="width: 528px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I am not receiving any errors and am totally stumped, any help or insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried stripping down your code to see if you can reproduce the error with the bare minimum code present? Often I find that I solve my own bugs doing this and it's generally a better thing to post on SO as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have simplified the code as much as possible here and on JSFiddle.  The Dropdown still does not trigger setData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your JSFiddle and changing to "Option B" and back to "Option A" does nothing simply because there is no change to the data. Both options (in the case of "Option C" and "Option E") set the data to the exact same values as the values that are present when the chart is created.

If you instead run the JSFiddle, set "Option D" and "Option F" before you start switching between "Option A" and "Option B" you will see that the code is clearly working as intended.

This can be confirmed by changing any one number in this if-branch:

```
if (selVal == "a" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "a") { ...
```

And/or this else if-branch:

```
else if (selVal == "b" && selValB == "a" && selValBB == "a") { ...
```

As shown in this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6QYzD/22/), which has only changed two numbers in the described cases.

That being said, this clearly illustrates that this code needs to be tidied up.

Comment: This answer is correct. Also, you have 3 dropdown menus, each of which gives you 2 choices. This means you should have a total of 2^3 = 8 different possible outcomes for each onChange function, but your if/else statements account for 10 different outcomes. You have 2 redundant if statements in every onChange function.

Comment: @Ondkloss Thank you very much for your help! I entirely forgot that some of the data could contain duplicate values! This solved the problem.

Comment: @jeebface Thanks for noticing the redundant if statements!